# am start of Chrome: Activity class does not exist

Tags: adb, chrome-for-android

I've downloaded Chrome 106.0.5249.79-524907934 from APKMirror and installed it (along with the corresponding Trichrome package) on a Pixel 5a via

```
$ unzip com.android.chrome_106.0.5249.79-524907934_8lang_11feat_..._apkmirror.com.apkm
$ adb install-multiple -r -d *.apk
```

So far, so good.  However, when I try to start the app via

```
$ adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

I get

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main} does not exist.
```

Running `adb logcat` at the same time shows

```
W PackageManager: Intent does not match component's intent filter: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main }
W PackageManager: Access blocked: ComponentInfo{com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main}
```

Comment: I just tried the command on Pixel 3a, Android 12 and it succeed. Could you open Chrome manually? Otherwise, check if Chrome is disabled or not, because it returned the same error when I disabled it.

Comment: I can load it manually.